# How to initialize the model using Window.dimensions in Elm?

Tags: dom, elm

In a sliding puzzle game, I'd like set the initial tile size based on the initial window dimensions (to maximize the screen real estate).

[image]

In other words, I'd like to set `initialModel` based on the the initial value of `Window.dimensions`.

I couldn't find how to do this, and ended up using ports to get the initial window dimensions:

**index.html**

```javascript
Elm.fullscreen(Elm.App, {
  windowSize: [
    document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    document.documentElement.clientHeight
  ]
});
```

**App.elm**

```elm
port windowSize : (Int, Int)

initialModel =
  -- some function of windowSize

model =
  Signal.foldp update initialModel input

type Action
  = WindowResize (Int, Int)
  | ...

windowResize =
  Signal.map WindowResize Window.dimensions

update action model =
  case action of
    WindowResize dimensions ->
      { model | some change based on dimensions }
  ...
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result without using ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Signal.Extra.foldp'](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.6.0/Signal-Extra#foldp%27) from the [Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.6.0/) package to inspect base the initial value of the model on the initial value of the input signal.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of that package.

Comment: So I can see how that allows me access to the initial value inside the second fn passed to foldp'. But I'm not sure what I can usefully do with that value to get it into my model. A little code sample would be very useful because I think I am missing something...

Comment: @JulianJelfs The second function allows you to turn an initial value into a value of your model. So in that function you put that initial value into the model, then in the step function you just consume the model as normal.